# Generating .equals method on java from wsdl files with axis2

Tags: java, wsdl, apache-axis

I want to try and compare a complex java object that is present in two different hierarchies, that is also generated from my wsdl file using axis2.

I understand that the standard .equals method I inherit from object is insufficient, so is there any way to generate this through a configuration of my axis2 plugin in my pom.xml file?

I can't find anything in the documentation for axis2, do you lads know if this is possible?

Comment: I do not think any automatic tool can decide for you when 2 objects are equal.  There is more to it than meets the eye.

Comment: I understand that. I want to auto generate an equals method within the java objects generated from my wsdl files. I understand this can be done with CXF, but I'm unsure if it can be done with axis2.